# KVM auto installation

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, centos, kvm

It's already third day that I am stuck.Basically I  am trying to write a bash script which 
will automatically install Centos 7 using KVM .
So I got tree kickstart files but none of them works .During installation I got

```
 Warning : /dev/root does not exist 
 dracut:/#
```

And it hangs
here is my kickstart file 
1

```
  install
  keyboard 'us'
  rootpw --iscrypted $1$Z69M4fwE$KuMSDb/VA0Fx9KPCZDqsK.
  timezone Asia/Yerevan
  lang en_US
  network \
  --device = eth0 \
  --bootproto = dhcp \
   --noipv6 \
  --activate
  firewall --enabled --ssh
   auth  --useshadow  --passalgo=sha512
   text
  selinux --enforcing
  skipx
  reboot
  bootloader --location = mbr --boot-drive = vda --append = "crashkernel                         = auto" 
 clearpart --none --initlabel 

 part / --fstype="xfs" --size=5000
 part swap --fstype="swap" --size=2000
 part /home --fstype="ext2" --size=10000
```

Any help is appreciated

I start to loose my hope ((